# How can I make my Get DataTable Method more Dynamic

Tags: c#, sql

I have created a class to make it easier to access my data from a sql database.

So from what you can see I have two overloaded DataTable methods that determine what table to pull from the Database based on which column.

The problem i cant seem to get my head around yet it seems so basic is, the "Value" variable is not always going to be an Integer. It could be a Date, String, Or Float Variable.

I want to know what would be the best coding practice in this situation without just making it a dynamic variable.
Would I just overload the method over and over? How ever having more then two tables and multiple scenarios this does not seem like it would be viable.

```
public abstract class dbData
{



    ///
    public enum AssmbliesColumn 
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns Entire Datatable.
        /// </summary>
        Fulltable = 0,

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns Single Assembly Datatable.
        /// </summary>
        AssemblyID = 1,

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns Single Assembly Datatable.
        /// </summary>
        AssemblyNo = 2,

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns multiple assemblies datatable based on JobID.
        /// </summary>
        JobID = 3,

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns single assembly datatable based on RFID No.
        /// </summary>
        RFID = 4,               


    };
    public enum JobsColumn
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns entire DataTable.
        /// </summary>
        Fulltable = 0,

        /// <summary>
        ///Returns DataTable based on JobID.
        /// </summary>
        JobId = 1,

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns DataTable based on JobNumber.
        /// </summary>
        JobNumber = 2,

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns DataTable based on JobClient.
        /// </summary>
        JobClient = 3,

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns DataTable based on BudgetHours
        /// </summary>

        BudgetHours = 4,
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns DataTable based on BudgetTonnage.
        /// </summary>

        BudgetTonnage = 5,

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns DataTable based on PurchaseOrder.
        /// </summary>
        PurchaseOrder = 6,
    }



/// <summary>
/// Returns Jobs Datatable
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dataValue"></param>
/// <param name="Column"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
    public static DataTable getDatatable(string Value, JobsColumn Column)
    {
         dataControls dbControl = new dataControls();

        string cmdString;
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();




                if ((int)Column == 0)
                {
                    cmdString = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Jobs";
                    sqlCmd.Connection = dbControl.connection;
                    sqlCmd.CommandText = cmdString;
                }

                if ((int)Column == 1)
                {
                    cmdString = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Jobs WHERE jobId = @jobid";
                    sqlCmd.Connection = dbControl.connection;
                    sqlCmd.CommandText = cmdString;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobid", Value);
                }
                if ((int)Column == 2)
                {
                    cmdString = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Jobs WHERE jobNumber = @jobnumber";
                    sqlCmd.Connection = dbControl.connection;
                    sqlCmd.CommandText = cmdString;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobnumber", Value);
                }
                if ((int)Column == 3)
                {
                    cmdString = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Jobs WHERE jobName = @jobname";
                    sqlCmd.Connection = dbControl.connection;
                    sqlCmd.CommandText = cmdString;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobname", Value);
                }

                if ((int)Column == 4)
                {
                    cmdString = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Jobs WHERE jobClient = @jobclient";
                    sqlCmd.Connection = dbControl.connection;
                    sqlCmd.CommandText = cmdString;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobclient", Value);
                }

                    dbControl.dbConnect();

        using (SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd))
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adap.Fill(dt);

            dbControl.dbDisconnect();
            return dt;

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns Assemblies Datatable
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Value"></param>
    /// <param name="Column"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DataTable getDatatable(int Value, AssmbliesColumn Column)
    {
        dataControls dbControl = new dataControls();

        string cmdString;
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();


        if (Column == 0)
        {
            cmdString = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Assemblies";
            sqlCmd.Connection = dbControl.connection;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = cmdString;
        }
        ///By AssemblyID
        if ((int)Column == 1)
        {
            cmdString = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Assemblies WHERE assemblyID = @assemblyid";
            sqlCmd.Connection = dbControl.connection;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = cmdString;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assemblyid", Value);
        }
        ///By AssemblyNo
        if ((int)Column == 2)
        {
            cmdString = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Assemblies WHERE assemblyNo = @assemblyno";
            sqlCmd.Connection = dbControl.connection;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = cmdString;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assemblyno", Value);
        }
        ///By JobID
        if ((int)Column == 3)
        {
            cmdString = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Assemblies WHERE jobID = @jobid";
            sqlCmd.Connection = dbControl.connection;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = cmdString;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobid", Value);
        }
        ///By RFID
        if ((int)Column == 4)
        {
            cmdString = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Assemblies WHERE RFID = @rfid";
            sqlCmd.Connection = dbControl.connection;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = cmdString;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rfid", Value);
        }

        dbControl.dbConnect();

        using (SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd))
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adap.Fill(dt);

            dbControl.dbDisconnect();
            return dt;

        }
    }
```

@patrickhofman

Would I be better off creating a class specific to the table I want to access?

```
   class Assemblies
{

    protected int? StoredID = null;
    protected string? StoredStringID = null;
    protected AssembliesColumn StoredColumn;

    public enum AssembliesColumn
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns Entire Datatable.
        /// </summary>
        Fulltable,
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns Single Assembly Datatable.
        /// </summary>
        AssemblyID,
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns Single Assembly Datatable.
        /// </summary>
        AssemblyString,
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns multiple assemblies datatable based on JobID.
        /// </summary>
        JobID,
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns single assembly datatable based on RFID No.
        /// </summary>
        RFID,


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// New Class Based on Integer ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ID"></param>
    /// <param name="Column"></param>
    public Assemblies(int ID, AssembliesColumn Column)
    {
        StoredColumn = Column;
        StoredID = ID;
                }

    public Assemblies(string ID, AssembliesColumn Column)
    {
        StoredColumn = Column;
        StoredStringID = ID;


    }


    public Assemblies(AssembliesColumn Column)
    {
        StoredColumn = Column;

    }

    public DataTable GetDataTable()
    {
        dataControls dbControl = new dataControls();
        string cmdString;
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

        try
        {
            switch (StoredColumn)
            {
                case AssembliesColumn.Fulltable:
                    cmdString = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Assemblies";
                sqlCmd.Connection = dbControl.connection;
                sqlCmd.CommandText = cmdString;
                    break;
                case AssembliesColumn.AssemblyID:
                    if (StoredID == null) throw new Exception("Assemblies ID Must be Integer Value");

                    cmdString = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Assemblies WHERE assemblyID = @assemblyid";
                    sqlCmd.Connection = dbControl.connection;
                    sqlCmd.CommandText = cmdString;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assemblyid", StoredID);
                    break;

                case AssembliesColumn.AssemblyString:
                    if (StoredStringID == null) throw new Exception("Assemblies ID Must be String Value");

                    cmdString = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Assemblies WHERE assemblyNo = @assemblyno";
                    sqlCmd.Connection = dbControl.connection;
                    sqlCmd.CommandText = cmdString;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assemblyno", StoredStringID);
                    break;

                case AssembliesColumn.JobID:
                    if (StoredStringID == null) throw new Exception("Assemblies ID Must be Integer Value");

                    cmdString = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Assemblies WHERE jobID = @jobid";
                    sqlCmd.Connection = dbControl.connection;
                    sqlCmd.CommandText = cmdString;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobid", StoredID);
                    break;
                case AssembliesColumn.RFID:
                    if (StoredStringID == null) throw new Exception("Assemblies ID Must be Integer Value");

                    cmdString = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Assemblies WHERE RFID = @rfid";
                    sqlCmd.Connection = dbControl.connection;
                    sqlCmd.CommandText = cmdString;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rfid", StoredID);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;

                    dbControl.dbConnect();

        using (SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            adap.Fill(dt);

            dbControl.dbDisconnect();
            return dt;

        }
            }
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());


        }


    }
}
}
```

Comment: First of all use a `switch` for `Column`.

Comment: Using one method for different kind of taks often decreases readability and increases the probability of errors.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Could you please explain to me how i might go about the basic structure for this type of class. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could make a good use of generics:

```
public static DataTable getDatatable<T>(T Value, AssmbliesColumn Column)
```

The function will use the type of variable `Value` you enter, like this:

```
DataTable d = getDatatable(1 /*int*/, AssmbliesColumn.Fulltable);
```

Or:

```
DataTable d = getDatatable("s" /*string*/, AssmbliesColumn.Fulltable);
```

Must be noted that your code eventually will go out of hand. If you need multiple parameters, you need an extra function. Why not make a method per value in your `enum` and call the generic method later?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply(not sure why I didn't have a switch statement.) Would you be able to elaborate a bit more on making the value in an enum? Regards

Comment: @BlaineWordly: Need more help?

Comment: I would like to get the structure of my code correct,  you say my code will get out if hand. Could you please explain where I might have gone wrong possibly with an example. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes if you could help that would be great. Even direct me to the right place to learn correct coding practices for this situation

Comment: Imagine what happens if you need extra parameters, extra queries, or simply want to check the data type of the field. Not possible now. Extract the generic part and the specific part.